# RSS feed created with PHP is not updating

Tags: php, xml, rss

I created a RSS feed using PHP. Basically using the header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

And then creating the xml string and outputting it.

Now the problem is even when I make changes to the PHP script that outputs the RSS feed, it takes forever for those changes to propogate and be seen in the RSS reader.

How do I overcome this problem ?

Comment: Via a link:<a href = 'all_minutes.php'>RSS</a> all_minutes.php is the one that has the script to echo out the RSS feed. When I click on the link it automatically opens up a RSS feed reader window

Comment: Are you sure the reader isn't looking at a cached version? Or caching a version by itself?

Comment: Perhaps you are right, this seems to be a problem on chrome/google reader. Not on firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using HTTP cache directives.

I'd suggest using this for testing:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And this for production:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=1800
```

It will make the content expire every 30 minutes (1800 = 30*60).

*Tip: Do not create the XML as a string. Use the [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) API to create the XML and it will be ALWAYS right. No strange encoding and stuff like that.*